# Presenting a UIViewController without animation shows the presenter UIViewController for an istant

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

```
// AppDelegate.swift

let navigationController = UINavigationController()
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
navigationController.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: false)
if !isLoggedIn {
    let authViewController = AuthViewController()
    navigationController.present(authViewController, animated: false)
}
```

I have a situation similar to this. If no user is authenticated, I want to show the authentication screen. The code above works but the problem is that, for a fraction of a second, I can see the HomeViewController before the AuthViewController is presented modally without animation. How can I prevent that?

Here's a GIF showing the problem.

[image: Animation]

Edit: I wouldn't want to use and if/else statement. I would like HomeViewController to always sit underneath AuthViewController.

Answer (score 2):

// APPDelegate

```
  -(void)launchScreen{
    UIStoryBoard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:USERID])
        {
            // here show the Dashboard or LoggedIn Screen
        }else{
             // here show the Login Screen or Authentication Screen
         }                                                                      
      }
```

Comment: I want to set HomeViewController as the root of the UINavigationController regardless

Comment: ok by Default u want to show homeViewController and inside app somewhere if user wants to login  or logged in u should show login screen and show logged in state am i right??

Comment: Yes, but they should never see HomeViewController if not logged in. I just want to put it in the hierarchy. That's why I want to immediately present AuthViewController above it if the user isn't logged in

Comment: should not see home VC by default ???ok can u tell me one thing when the app launches which screen u want to show Login Screen Or Home Screen ? so that i can tell u how to manage

Comment: is ur Problem Solved??

Comment: I always want to push HomeViewController in the stack but I do not necessarily want it to be visible to the user. It is visible only if the user has logged in; otherwise I want to present AuthViewController above it without animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150396/discussion-between-ramesh-and-lucamegh).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a if/else bloc?

```
if !isLoggedIn {
    let authViewController = AuthViewController()
    navigationController.present(authViewController, animated: false)
} else {
    let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
    navigationController.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Because I need HomeViewController to be always underneath AuthViewController. Once registered, AuthViewController will be dismissed. When the user logs out, AuthViewController gets presented

Comment: When user just logged in, you can present HomeViewController then dismiss AuthViewController. Or did you try to place the if block before presenting the HomeViewController ?

Comment: Yes I could do that but that's not the effect I want to achieve. I tried placing the if block before presenting HomeViewController but I get the same stutter

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your HomeViewController is being created in full before you check whether or not the user is authenticated. Move the code that checks authentication into your HomeViewController, in the viewDidLoad method and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I do not make my view controllers aware of each other. I'm using the [coordination pattern](http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/) so I cannot do that. The code I provided does not show that but implies that I'm constrained by that situation

Comment: well my VCs are always lean ;) if you do move the code, does the problem go away? If so, at least we know the source of the bug, then you can fit it into this new fancy pattern :D

Comment: The code I provided is exactly the one I'm using. It's just arranged differently. It could be possibile that what I'm asking is not feasible!

Comment: Ye of little faith! I'm saying just *try* moving it to the HomeViewController (5min) to see if that makes a difference. If it does, then we know why the view is being shown. If it doesn't make a difference, it's a different bug.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is at viewDidLoad time for the red view controller I load (loadNibNamed:owner:options:) a copy of my launch screen (a view controller) and add that controller's root view to the root view of the red guy. That way the red guy is hiding behind what appears to still be the launch screen.
(Make sure that at viewDidLayoutSubviews time the fake launch screen's frame is set to red guy's bounds.)

Then get rid of the fake launch screen after your login controller is up and covering it. Or if you never bring up the login controller just animate an alpha fade on the fake guy and remove it from the red guy's root view.

You'll likely need to keep track of the first time the red guy appears (or other say login state) in it's viewDidAppear: method.